# Objective C stringWithFormat if statement

Tags: objective-c, if-statement, stringwithformat, stringwithstring

I'm pretty new to this - I'm trying to compare a NSString stringWithFormat with some text. It works fine with stringWithString. I can't work out why it doesn't work with stringWithFormat? 
Many thanks for any help anyone can offer!

```
    NSString *theQuestion = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"The same thing"];
if (theQuestion == @"The same thing"){
        NSLog(@"stringWithFormat is the same as the given text");
    }else{
NSLog(@"stringWithFormat is NOT the same as the given text");
        NSLog(@"but theQuestion is:\"%@\"", theQuestion);
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`==` is a reference equal. to do a string compare it has to be the

```
if([theQuestion isEqualToString:@"The same thing"]){

}
```

Comment: Thanks - figured it out seconds after I posted - spent the last 2 days trying to work this out!

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
NSString *theQuestion = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"The same thing"];
```

Comment: Also, Use `isEqualToString method`, not `==`: `if ([theQuestion isEqualToString:@"The same thing"]){`

Comment: `StringWithFormat: @"The same thing"` should be fine, although useless. I would use `stringWithString: @"The same thing"` instead.

Comment: …Or just `NSString *theQuestion = @"The same thing";`.